# 'ORA-00904: "RIGHT": invalid identifier' Error in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

Query the list of CITY names from STATION which have vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, and u) as both their first and last characters. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

The station table is as follows:

[image: station table]

When I'm writing this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE (LEFT(CITY,1) IN ('A','E','I','O','U')) AND (RIGHT(CITY,1) IN ('A','E','I','O','U'));**
```

I'm getting an error:

> ORA-00904: "RIGHT": invalid identifier

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image, This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. [ask]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Based on the error message, I changed the database tag from `mysql` to `oracle`.

Answer (score 3):

`left()` and `right()` are not a thing in Oracle. Instead, you can use `substr()`. You can pass a negative starting index to get the last character:

```
select city 
from station 
where substr(city, 1, 1) in ('a','e','i','o','u') 
  and substr(city, -1) in ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

I am unsure that you really need `distinct` here, so I removed it - you can put if back if that's required for some reason.

You *could* also express this with a regular expression; this makes for shorter code, but will most likely be less efficient than simple string functions:

```
where regexp_like(city, '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'
```

Note that this is not strictly identical to the other solution, since it requires at least two characters in the string (while the first query would happily allow a city called `'a'`)